# Access data part in ERC 1155 Token

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft, defi, erc-1155

I'm new to the DEFI and blockchain concepts. So spare me if this is a lame question.
I am working on a project that needs data to be encoded and fed into the ERC 1155 token. I made a dummy contract that encodes certain data and feeds it into the data part in the ERC 1155 minting function and the transaction was successful. But is it possible for me to see the data in that token. Also if I am sending this token to another contract, how can they obtain this data and decode it?